# DFS Snake solving algorithm (NoneType object has no len)

Tags: python, pygame, depth-first-search, path-finding

I am making a snake solving algorithm using DFS (Depth-first search) on a grid. The snake works most of the time but I keep getting this error.

My friend has also posted a similar question about BFS (breadth-first search) we are in the same group and having the same error

Here is some output from a full run of the game until it has this NoneType error. The start position indicates where the head of the snake is. The food position indicates where the food that you are pathfinding to is, the array after the food position is the path to the current food, and the tuple after that is the direction it should turn to advance forward along its path. Whenever the snake eats the food the food position is then randomized and outputted to the console with the title NEW FOOD. I believe I know why the code is crashing but I'm cant figure out how to fix it. The algorithm is trying to find a path with the old food position while the snake is on the food which generates a null path because they path of the snake would have a length of 0. even though a new food position is already generated. This code works most of the time with the path but there must be a special case somewhere that is causing this issue.

Scroll down all the way for the main method

```
start: 
(9.0, 9.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(9, 9), (9, 8), (9, 7), (9, 6), (8, 6), (7, 6), (6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(0, -1)
turned
moved
start: 
(9.0, 8.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(9, 8), (9, 7), (9, 6), (8, 6), (7, 6), (6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(0, -1)
turned
moved
start: 
(9.0, 7.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(9, 7), (9, 6), (8, 6), (7, 6), (6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(0, -1)
turned
moved
start: 
(9.0, 6.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(9, 6), (8, 6), (7, 6), (6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(8.0, 6.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(8, 6), (7, 6), (6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(7.0, 6.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(7, 6), (6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(6.0, 6.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(5.0, 6.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(4.0, 6.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(3.0, 6.0)
food:
(2.0, 6.0)
[(3, 6), (2, 6)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
The score is 1
NEW FOOD: (7.0, 9.0)
start:
(2.0, 6.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(2, 6), (3, 6), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 6), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(1.0, 6.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(0, 1)
turned
moved
start: 
(1.0, 7.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(2.0, 7.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(3.0, 7.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(4.0, 7.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(5.0, 7.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(6.0, 7.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(7.0, 7.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]
(0, 1)
turned
moved
start: 
(7.0, 8.0)
food:
(7.0, 9.0)
[(7, 8), (7, 9)]
(0, 1)
turned
moved
The score is 2
NEW FOOD: (14.0, 9.0)
start:
(7.0, 9.0)
food:
(14.0, 9.0)
[(7, 9), (8, 9), (9, 9), (10, 9), (11, 9), (12, 9), (13, 9), (14, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(8.0, 9.0)
food:
(14.0, 9.0)
[(8, 9), (9, 9), (10, 9), (11, 9), (12, 9), (13, 9), (14, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(9.0, 9.0)
food:
(14.0, 9.0)
[(9, 9), (10, 9), (11, 9), (12, 9), (13, 9), (14, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(10.0, 9.0)
food:
(14.0, 9.0)
[(10, 9), (11, 9), (12, 9), (13, 9), (14, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(11.0, 9.0)
food:
(14.0, 9.0)
[(11, 9), (12, 9), (13, 9), (14, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(12.0, 9.0)
food:
(14.0, 9.0)
[(12, 9), (13, 9), (14, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(13.0, 9.0)
food:
(14.0, 9.0)
[(13, 9), (14, 9)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
The score is 3
NEW FOOD: (1.0, 4.0)
start:
(14.0, 9.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(14, 9), (14, 8), (14, 7), (14, 6), (14, 5), (14, 4), (13, 4), (12, 4), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 
4)]
(0, -1)
turned
moved
start: 
(14.0, 8.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(14, 8), (14, 7), (14, 6), (14, 5), (14, 4), (13, 4), (12, 4), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]      
(0, -1)
turned
moved
start: 
(14.0, 7.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(14, 7), (14, 6), (14, 5), (14, 4), (13, 4), (12, 4), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(0, -1)
turned
moved
start: 
(14.0, 6.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(14, 6), (14, 5), (14, 4), (13, 4), (12, 4), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(0, -1)
turned
moved
start: 
(14.0, 5.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(14, 5), (14, 4), (13, 4), (12, 4), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(0, -1)
turned
moved
start: 
(14.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(14, 4), (13, 4), (12, 4), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(13.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(13, 4), (12, 4), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(12.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(12, 4), (11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(11.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(11, 4), (10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(10.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(10, 4), (9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(9.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(9, 4), (8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(8.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(8, 4), (7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(7.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(7, 4), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(6.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(5.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(4.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(3.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(2.0, 4.0)
food:
(1.0, 4.0)
[(2, 4), (1, 4)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
The score is 4
NEW FOOD: (15.0, 5.0)
start:
(1.0, 4.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(0, 1)
turned
moved
start: 
(1.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(2.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(3.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(4.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(5.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(6.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(7.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(8.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(9.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(10.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(10, 5), (11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(11.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(11, 5), (12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(12.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(12, 5), (13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(13.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(13, 5), (14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(14.0, 5.0)
food:
(15.0, 5.0)
[(14, 5), (15, 5)]
(1, 0)
turned
moved
The score is 5
NEW FOOD: (11.0, 8.0)
start:
(15.0, 5.0)
food:
(11.0, 8.0)
[(15, 5), (15, 6), (15, 7), (15, 8), (14, 8), (13, 8), (12, 8), (11, 8)]
(0, 1)
turned
moved
start: 
(15.0, 6.0)
food:
(11.0, 8.0)
[(15, 6), (15, 7), (15, 8), (14, 8), (13, 8), (12, 8), (11, 8)]
(0, 1)
turned
moved
start: 
(15.0, 7.0)
food:
(11.0, 8.0)
[(15, 7), (15, 8), (14, 8), (13, 8), (12, 8), (11, 8)]
(0, 1)
turned
moved
start: 
(15.0, 8.0)
food:
(11.0, 8.0)
[(15, 8), (14, 8), (13, 8), (12, 8), (11, 8)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(14.0, 8.0)
food:
(11.0, 8.0)
[(14, 8), (13, 8), (12, 8), (11, 8)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(13.0, 8.0)
food:
(11.0, 8.0)
[(13, 8), (12, 8), (11, 8)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
start: 
(12.0, 8.0)
food:
(11.0, 8.0)
[(12, 8), (11, 8)]
(-1, 0)
turned
moved
The score is 6
NEW FOOD: (17.0, 9.0)
start:
(11.0, 8.0)
food:
(17.0, 9.0)
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\person\Desktop\Snake\dfs.py", line 387, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\person\Desktop\Snake\dfs.py", line 369, in main
    snake_dir = snake_directions(path).pop()
  File "c:\Users\person\Desktop\Snake\dfs.py", line 295, in snake_directions
    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
PS C:\Users\person\Desktop\Snake>
```

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
import heapq as hq
from pygame.display import update
#import splashscreen

SCREEN_WIDTH = 720
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720

GRIDSIZE = 40
GRID_WIDTH = int(SCREEN_HEIGHT / GRIDSIZE)
GRID_HEIGHT = int(SCREEN_WIDTH / GRIDSIZE)

UP = (0, -1)
DOWN = (0, 1)
LEFT = (-1, 0)
RIGHT = (1, 0)

times_in = 0

class Snake(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 1
        self.positions = [((SCREEN_WIDTH / 2), (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2))]
        self.direction = random.choice([UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT])
        self.color = (240, 240, 240)
        self.tail = (0, 0)

    def get_head_position(self):
        return self.positions[0]

    def turn(self, point):
        if self.length > 1 and (point[0] * -1, point[1] * -1) == self.direction:
            return
        else:
            self.direction = point

    def move(self):
        cur = self.get_head_position()
        x, y = self.direction
        new = (((cur[0] + (x*GRIDSIZE))), (cur[1] + (y*GRIDSIZE)))
        if (len(self.positions) > 2 and new in self.positions[2:-1]) or new[0] == -GRIDSIZE or new[1] == -GRIDSIZE or new[0] == SCREEN_WIDTH or new[1] == SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.reset()
            reset_grid()
            food.randomize_position()
        else:
            
            for i in self.positions:
                grid[int(i[1] / GRIDSIZE), int(i[0] / GRIDSIZE)] = 1
            
            grid[int(new[1] / GRIDSIZE), int(new[0] / GRIDSIZE)] = 3
            
            if len(self.positions) + 1 > self.length:
                old = self.positions.pop()
                grid[int(old[1] / GRIDSIZE), int(old[0] / GRIDSIZE)] = 0
            self.positions.insert(0, new)
            grid[int(self.positions[-1][1] / GRIDSIZE), int(self.positions[-1][0] / GRIDSIZE)] = 4
            self.tail = self.positions[-1]

    def reset(self):
        global score
        self.length = 1
        self.positions = [((SCREEN_WIDTH / 2), (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2))]
        self.direction = random.choice([UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT])
        score = 0
    
    def draw(self, surface):
        for index, p in enumerate(self.positions):
            r = pygame.Rect((p[0], p[1]), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE))
            if index == 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (230, 0, 255), r)
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (93, 216, 228), r, 1)
                continue
            if index == snake.length - 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 230, 255), r)
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (93, 216, 228), r, 1)
                continue
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, (abs(240 - 4*index), abs(240 - 4*index), abs(240 - 4*index)), r)
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, (93, 216, 228), r, 1)

    def handle_keys(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.turn(UP)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.turn(DOWN)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.turn(LEFT)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.turn(RIGHT)

class Food(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = (0, 0)
        self.color = (114, 137, 218)
        self.randomize_position()

    def get_position(self):
        return self.position

    def randomize_position(self):
        grid[int(self.position[1]/GRIDSIZE), int(self.position[0]/GRIDSIZE)] = 0
        self.position = (random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH-1) * GRIDSIZE, random.randint(0, GRID_HEIGHT-1) * GRIDSIZE)
        #if the 
        if self.position in snake.positions:
            self.randomize_position() #recursive call
        grid[int(self.position[1]/GRIDSIZE), int(self.position[0]/GRIDSIZE)] = 2

    def draw(self, surface):
        r = pygame.Rect((self.position[0], self.position[1]), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE))
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, r)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (93, 216, 228), r, 1)

    def get_position(self):
        return self.position

def drawGrid(surface, myfont):
    for y in range(0, int(GRID_HEIGHT)):
        for x in range(0, int(GRID_WIDTH)):
            if (x + y) % 2 == 0:
                r = pygame.Rect((x*GRIDSIZE, y*GRIDSIZE), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE))
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (44, 47, 51), r)
                text = myfont.render(str((x, y)), 1, (0, 0, 0))
                surface.blit(text, ((x*GRIDSIZE, y*GRIDSIZE), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE)))
            else:
                rr = pygame.Rect((x*GRIDSIZE, y*GRIDSIZE), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE))
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (35, 39, 42), rr)
                text = myfont.render(str((x, y)), 1, (0, 0, 0))
                surface.blit(text, ((x*GRIDSIZE, y*GRIDSIZE), (GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE)))

class Node():
    def __init__(self, position, parent = None):
        self.position = (int(position[0]), int(position[1]))
        #parent is the parent node
        self.parent = parent
    
    # Compare Nodes
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.position == other.position

    # Print Nodes
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.position)

    def get_parent(self):
        return self.parent

    def get_neighbors(self):
        #returns neighbors (UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT)
        #THIS DOES NOT MEAN THE NEIGHBORING POSITIONS ARE not obstacles
        parent_pos = self.position
        x = parent_pos[0]
        y = parent_pos[1]

        children = []
        for new_position in [UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT]:

            node_position = (self.position[0] + new_position[0], self.position[1] + new_position[1])

            temp = self
            broken = False
            while temp is not None:
                if (temp.position == node_position):
                    broken = True
                    break
                temp = temp.parent

            if broken:
                continue


            if node_position[0] >= (GRID_HEIGHT - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] >= (GRID_HEIGHT -1) or node_position[1] < 0:
                continue

            # if grid[node_position[0], node_position[1]] != 0 and grid[node_position[0], node_position[1]] != 2 and grid[node_position[0], node_position[1]] != 4:
            #     continue

            if (grid[node_position[1], node_position[0]] == 1 or grid[node_position[1], node_position[0]] == 3 or (grid[node_position[1], node_position[0]] == 4)):
                continue

            new_node = Node(node_position, self)

            children.append(new_node)
        return children

    def on_grid(self):
        x = self.position[0]
        y = self.position[1]
        return (x >= GRID_WIDTH or x < 0 or y >= GRID_HEIGHT or y < 0)
    
    def is_snake_node(self, snake):
        x = self.position[0]
        y = self.position[1]
        
        for pos in snake.positions:
            if (pos[0] == x and pos[1] == y):
                return True
        return False
    
    def get_position(self):
        return self.position
    
    #this method traces through its parents and adds their positions to a list
    #order would be [1st gen node, 2nd gen node, ..., this node]
    def listify(self):
        list = []
        list.insert(0, self.position)

        node = self.parent
        while node is not None:
            list.insert(0, node.position)
            node = node.parent
        return list

def mult_node_is_obstacle(nodes):
        return_bools = []
        for node in nodes:
            return_bools.append(node.on_grid() and (not node.is_snake_node))
            
        return return_bools

#food = Food()
def dfs(start_pos, goal_pos):
    open_list = []
    closed_list = []

    start_node = Node(start_pos)
    goal_node = Node(goal_pos)

    open_list.append(start_node)

    while (len(open_list) != 0):
        cur_node = open_list.pop(-1)

        closed_list.append(cur_node)
        
        if (cur_node == goal_node):
            path = []
            while cur_node != start_node:
                path.append(cur_node.get_position())
                cur_node = cur_node.get_parent()
            #code before wouldnt insert start node into path so i added it here
            path.append(start_node.get_position())

            return path[::-1]

        cur_x = (start_node.get_position())[0]
        cur_y = (start_node.get_position())[1]
        goal_x = goal_node.get_position()[0]
        goal_y = goal_node.get_position()[1]

        cur_node_neighbors = cur_node.get_neighbors()
        #array to see if neighbors are obstacles
        #Checks to see if there are available nodes

        for child in cur_node_neighbors:
            #if the node isnt an obstacle and it isnt in the closed list then add it to the open list
            #adds child nodes to open list 
            if child in closed_list:
                continue

            if child not in open_list:
                open_list.insert(0, child)
    
    return None
        


            
score = 0
grid = 0
def reset_grid():
    global grid
    grid = np.zeros((GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT))
    grid = grid.astype(int)

reset_grid()
# 0 = empty
# 1 = snake piece
# 3 = snake head
# 2 = food
# 4 = end of snake

directions = []

def snake_directions(path):
    directions = []

    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
        direction_vector = (path[i + 1][0] - path[i][0], path[i + 1][1] - path[i][1])
        directions.insert(0,direction_vector)
    return directions

def dead():
    snake.reset()
    reset_grid()
    food.randomize_position()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                print(event)
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    splashscreen.game_intro()

food = 0
snake = 0
surface = 0
depth = 0
MAX_DEPTH = 0

def main():
    global score, food, snake, surface, simulated
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), 0, 32)

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 16)

    surface = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    surface = surface.convert()
    drawGrid(surface, myfont)

    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()

    #print(a_star((0, SCREEN_WIDTH - 20), (SCREEN_HEIGHT - 20, SCREEN_WIDTH - 20), Snake()))
    while (True):
        
        clock.tick(15)
        #snake.handle_keys()
        #drawGrid(surface, myfont)
        #snake.move()
        
        #simulated = False
        #print("test")
        
            
        if snake.get_head_position() == food.get_position():
            snake.length += 1
            score = snake.length - 1
            food.randomize_position()
            print("The score is {}".format(score))
            print("NEW FOOD: (" + str(food.get_position()[0] / GRIDSIZE) + ", " + str(food.get_position()[1] / GRIDSIZE) + ")")

        snake.draw(surface)
        food.draw(surface)
        screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
        text = myfont.render("Score {0}".format(score), 1, (255, 255, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (5, 10))
        
        drawGrid(surface, myfont)
        
        start_pos = (snake.get_head_position()[0]/GRIDSIZE, snake.get_head_position()[1]/GRIDSIZE)
        food_pos = (food.get_position()[0] / GRIDSIZE, food.get_position()[1]/GRIDSIZE)

        print('start: ')
        print(start_pos)
        print('food: ')
        print(food_pos)
        path = dfs(start_pos, food_pos)
        print(path)
        snake_dir = snake_directions(path).pop()
        print(snake_dir)

        snake.turn(snake_dir)
        print("turned")
        snake.move()
        print("moved")

        
         
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                print("test")
        #print("test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple:

Line 204 in `Node.get_neigbors` you added a condition to check if a children (neighbor) is on the grid:

```
if node_position[0] >= (GRID_HEIGHT - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 \
or node_position[1] >= (GRID_HEIGHT - 1) or node_position[1] < 0:
    continue
```

you are checking if the x / y position is `>= (GRID_HEIGHT - 1)`. so if the position is equal to `GRID_HEIGHT - 1`, meaning it is on the leftmost column / bottom row it is detected by the `>=` and is discarded. therefore if the food happens to spawn in this row or column, `dfs` is unable to find a path to the food and returns `None`, which is passed to `snake_directions`, raising an Error.

Fix:

```
if node_position[0] >= GRID_WIDTH or node_position[0] < 0 \  # use GRID_WIDTH for the x-axis check
    or node_position[1] >= GRID_HEIGHT or node_position[1] < 0:
    continue
```

NOTE:
if the snake is unable to find a path because the way is blocked by the snakes body the same error will be raised. (you can fix this by adding a "waiting behavior" e.g. in line 224 for this)

Comment: Your answer gave some valuable insight. Your response was correct in the words but you forgot to alter the if statement to count the final row/column instead of discarding it

Comment: The fix was to both change the variable and then remove the -1 from all the stuff. Thank you for your response!! I've been debugging this for way too long

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I was pretty tired when I wrote the answer so yeah... I just fixed the answer.